# Simultaneous similarity of pairs of $2\times2$-matrices over algebraically closed fields

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, similar-matrices

This problem should be simple enough to solve by hand, but I don't have any good approach.

> Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field. Consider matrices $A_1, A_2, B_1, B_2 \in M_2(K)$. Find a criterion equivalent to the simultaneous similarity of $(A_1, A_2)$ and $(B_1, B_2)$, i.e. there exists some $X \in \mathrm{GL}_2(K)$ such that $X A_1 X^{-1} = A_2$ and $X B_1 X^{-1} = B_2$.

In this case, each matrix above has an eigenvalue decomposition, i.e. is diagonalisable.

Comment: What approaches have you considered so far? You can let us know what the disadvantages/roadblocks that you found are, so others can think of other approaches

Comment: @TonyMathew Tbh, nothing helpful. I thought about how to find $X$ given $P,Q\in\mathrm{GL}_2(K)$ such that $PA_1P^{-1}=A_2$ and $QB_1Q^{-1}=B_2$, but $P,Q$ as a change of basis are unique (i.e. if $A_1\sim A_2$, then there is only one $P$ to make that happen).

Comment: @Gargantuar They define simultaneous similarity as the case where $P=Q$